# Replace certain elements in lists of lists

Tags: python, list

How to replace certain elements, if I may have lists of lists in python? I am only interested to change individual elements

```
def replace_item(the_list,toBeReplaced,toBeReplacedBy):
    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item,list):
            replace_item(each_item,toBeReplaced,toBeReplacedBy)
        else:
           if each_item == toBeReplaced:
                each_item=toBeReplacedBy

    return the_list
```

Like if I have a list

```
[[2,3],[[2,3,5,6],2,6,3],[1,2]]
```

and if I want to replace 2 by say zero then resultant should be

```
[[0,3],[[0,3,5,6],0,6,3],0,6,3,[1,0]]
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am not able replace certain value by certain values by this function. Why ?

Comment: The list may be nested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by assigning toBeReplacedBy to each_item you are not changing the item in the_list. This is how you do it.

```
def replace_item(the_list,toBeReplaced,toBeReplacedBy):
        for index,each_item in enumerate(the_list):
            if isinstance(each_item,list):
                replace_item(each_item,toBeReplaced,toBeReplacedBy)
            else:
                if each_item == toBeReplaced:
                    the_list[index]=toBeReplacedBy

        return the_list
```

Comment: I am using this code but it is giving me the error
emp=ri.replace_item(P,float('Inf'),10000)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-79-4332883a83eb>", line 1, in <module>
    temp=ri.replace_item(P,float('Inf'),10000)

  File "replace_item.py", line 36, in replace_item
    print each_item

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: try this, replace_item(the_list[index],toBeReplaced,toBeReplacedBy) instead of replace_item(each_item,toBeReplaced,toBeReplacedBy)

Comment: No dnit13 as it is a numpy array then it wont work like that because isinstance()  itself returns false in this case